QGIS 3D Map View : how to set image resolution on export
QGIS 3.36.1 on MacOS 13.6.6
From a 3D geopkg layer (LOD2) in a 3D map view I would like to export an image with higher resolution. Actually the exported image seems to have only 72 ppi. Is there a possiblity to set the exporting image resolution?
